# How can I concatenate my array with strcat

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char str[800];

   char insert[7] = "insert ";
   char* ip = &insert;


   strcpy (str,"these ");
   strcat (str,"strings ");
   strcat (str,"are ");

   strcat (str, ip);
   // or? strcat (str, insert);

   strcat (str,"concatenated.");

   printf("%s\n", str);

}
```

So im having trouble adding the array 'insert' to the array 'str'. Im not sure if I have to use a pointer for insert or not. Ive tried a few different ways but cant seem to get it to print "these strings are insert concatenated".

Comment: Or char * ip = &insert[0];

Comment: why use `char* ip = &insert;` instead of just `insert` if you are not doing any arithmetic with the pointer?

Comment: thanks its working now. I somehow complicated it in my mind...

Comment: Best get into the habit of using `strncat` and `strncpy` whenever you can, it's safer

Comment: the line: char insert[7] = "insert "; will fail during a strcat operation as strcat expects the added string to be '\0' terminated and the string "insert " needs 8 characters to include the '\0', so the line strcat( str, ip ); will not stop adding characters until a '\0' is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do-

```
char insert[7] = "insert ";
char* ip = &insert;
```

Here you are assigning address of address of the char array. Not address of Char array.
Due to that if you compile your program you will get warning as-

```
edit.c: In function ‘main’:
edit.c:9:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

So try this change-

```
char insert[7] = "insert ";
char *ip = insert;
```

only assign the address of the char array. Not the address of address of char array

or

```
char *ip = "insert ";
```

This also will work for you!

**Else**
as you mentioned you can follow this way also-

```
int main ()
{
   char str[800];

   char insert[7] = "insert ";


   strcpy (str,"these ");
   strcat (str,"strings ");
   strcat (str,"are ");

   strcat (str, insert);

   strcat (str,"concatenated.");

   printf("%s\n", str);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this initialization instead

```
char insert[] = "insert ";
char *ip = insert;
```

This way you make sure the corresponding string is null-terminated and you don't have incompatible-pointer-type problem.

Note : Ani has kindly pointed out that the initialization `char insert[7] = "insert ";` is not portable (which is logical since the size should be 8 when the null `char` is included). Apparently it causes segfault on some compiler(s).

Comment: Do you mean `char *ip = "insert "`?

Comment: No, `insert` is the name of the `char` array the OP declared.

Comment: Then it gives segmentation fault!

Comment: Interesting. How did you declare `insert`?

Comment: Then it should be fine. What did you use `ip` or `insert` for afterwards?

Comment: No further changes, just what you have specified. Used `ip`.

Comment: Everything is fine on my side. I suggest you post a question about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60398/discussion-between-ani-and-downhillfromhere).

Answer (score 0):

When you use strcpy, according to manual page, it will copy the str starting at the adress you provide him in the first argument.

So instead of doing

```
strcpy(str, "strings");
```

try giving him the adress at which your string finish

```
strcpy(str + strlen(str), "strings ");
```

and so on

Comment: True but the question is about `strcat`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `char insert[7] = "insert ";` it is not required.

Change `char *ip = &insert;` to `char *ip = "insert "`

Comment: @Coconop: Made the changes :)

Answer (score 0):

There is basically one problem that makes the code not to work.

The problem is that in your code you assign the following way:

```
char* ip = &insert;
```

when it really should be:

```
char* ip = insert;
```

The variable `insert` is not an array. It's a pointer to a spot allocated for the program. Basically - it's just a pointer to the first element in the array.

Means:

```
insert[0] = 'a';
```

is the same as:

```
*insert = 'a';
```

So the address of insert is a pointer TO THE POINTER that points to the array.

You could either just put a `*` operator TWICE (`**` - something like 'the content of the content of...[some variable which is usually a pointer]) before the `ip` in the `strcat` use OR you could just type `strcat(str, insert);` because in this program there is no need for the variable `ip` at all.

One more mistake is not saving room for the NULL terminator `\0` that announces the end of a string.

So either you type `char insert[] = "insert ";` which determines the size of the array according to the direct assignment OR you could do `char insert[8] = "insert ";` which is basically the size of that string (it needs a NULL terminator so it's 'i', 'n', 's', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ' and '\0').

Answer (score 0):

```
$man strcat

char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

You can either:

```
strcat (str, ip);
```

Or

```
strcat(str, insert);
```

Provided you correctly initialized your string:

```
   char insert[] = "insert ";
   char * ip = insert;
```